# How to execute other file from script body in sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

How I can execute other file in ms sql script for sqlcmd?

In sqlplus I can write something as:

```
@@DBS\other_scr1.sql
@@DBS\other_scr2.sql

promt OK
```

Comment: Consider putting them in a stored procedure and call via the `EXECUTE` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the script file

Open a command prompt window.
In the Command Prompt window, type:

```
        sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql
```

Press ENTER.
A list of Adventure Works employee names and addresses is written to the command prompt window.

To save this output to a text file
Open a command prompt window.
In the Command Prompt window, type:

```
    sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql -o C:\EmpAdds.txt
```

Press ENTER.

If you want to execute that through SQL Script.

Use xp_cmdshell which will ultimetly SQLCMD.
Thanks

Comment: It'ss from batch script and its copypaste from msdn.
I know it and I want run sql script from sql script.

Comment: In that case you will have to use xp_cmdshell which will call SQLCMD.

Comment: Maybe not bad. Thx